Trainee hitman attempts to kill a woman as a test target but misses
There is a trainee hitman with a mentor who tries to teach him the profession. As a final test the trainee is asked to kill a randomly selected person, a young single woman working at the library. He attempts to kill her in her house with a sniper rifle but he misses the shots and the woman manages to escape from him. The trainee and the mentor must eliminate her so they start their search. The woman starts training herself for self defense by reading books and going to the shotting range. The trainee hitman slowly starts having feelings towards the target. The librarian finally becomes a better assassin on her own and manages to kill the hitman then she teams up with the mentor and they start working together. The film is probably from the late 90's or from the early 2000s.

I think it may be Angel's Dance (1999)- however the targeted woman works at a mortuary.

Tony wants to be a hitman for the Mafia, but first he has to learn from a master. Enter Stevie "California" Rossellini - cool, eats veggie dogs and quotes Nietzsche. Greco may not agree with Stevie's style, but he has to complete his training so he can go back and kill the Mafia's accountant, who is about to turn state's evidence. His final test: kill whoever is supposedly randomly picked out of the yellow pages. His target: Angelica "Angel" Chaste, a very disturbed woman. Tony falls for Angel and fails to kill her, so Stevie sets out to finish the job.

From an IMDb review:

The story opens on the streets of Chicago, where a businessman is
  being stalked by a mob hitman. Just as he is about to strike, the
  hitman is run over by a truck! We learn that the businessman is the
  former accountant for the mob boss, Uncle Vinny (Jon Polito of
  "Miller's Crossing"), and he is entering the witness protection
  program in order to testify against Vinny.
A new hitman is needed pronto, and Tony Greco (Kyle Chandler), who
  once took a bullet to protect another mobster, is elected. Tony is
  sent to California to train with Stevie Rosellini (Jim Belushi), the
  most-feared assassin in the country. But Stevie turns out to be a
  laid-back California dude who lives on the beach and quotes Nietzche,
  so there is plenty of humor involving the clash between their personal
  styles and values.
After training Tony for a while, Stevie reveals the final test Tony
  must pass before he can return to Chicago--killing an innocent victim
  selected at random from the phone book. The victim selected is Angel
  Chaste (Sheryl Lee), who turns out to be a mortician at a funeral
  parlor.
As Stevie and Tony start tailing Angel, they learn that her life is a
  bit more complicated that it appears. When Angel discovers what is
  going on, she uses her intelligence and wit and turns into a far more
  formidable target than the assassins ever encountered.

From screeninsults.com:

Initially, Tony's first shot misses his target and hits a bottle of
  pills that Angela was contemplating taking during her suicide attempt,
  but the gunfire shocks Angela back to reality and she runs for her
  life, goes undercover, reads up on firearms, dons a blond wig and
  begins to hunt her hunters.
When Tony becomes infatuated with Angela, it falls to Stevie to
  conclude the contract. But first he has to get Angela, and that proves
  very, very hard indeed.

